# How do you nest/merge 2 or more partial classes .net vs2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a set of partial classes and I would like to be nested.

If I wanted to do it manually what do I need to modify?
There were some visual studio extensions in the past but not for vs2022

thanks

Update

Suppose I have a class called MyService.cs
but I would like to create partial classes like

MyService.AAA.cs
MyService.BBB.cs
MyService.CCC.cs

I would like them to be nested like pic below (just a sample)

[image]

Comment: Please post some of your partial classes and explain in more detail what you want to achieve with them.

Comment: Try https://github.com/NicoB1981/FileNesting

Comment: Absolutely do NOT try github.com/NicoB1981/FileNesting  , that extension is more or less obsolete because nesting is standard in VS 2022.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectCapability Include="ConfigurableFileNesting" />
  <ProjectCapability Include="ConfigurableFileNestingFeatureEnabled" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And then if you look in *Solution Explorer* there should be a button you can click to turn the nesting on and off:

[image: Button to enable file nesting]

(It's the button just above the top-left of the tooltip in the image.)

You may need to close and reopen the project for the change to the `.csproj` file to take effect.

NOTE: This applies to SDK-style `.csproj` files only.

Also note that if you're using a web app, there's a separate setting which you select by clicking the drop-arrow on the right of the File Nesting button:

[image: Web settings]

Comment: Hi thanks for that - done what you said but it says file nesting disabled - cannot see how to enable it. I have restarted the project

Comment: Got it the settings but set to web settings. thank you

Comment: @developer9969 I'll add that to the answer, in case anyone else needs this information.

Comment: I'm quite puzzled because I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (17.5.4) and the file Nesting is enabled in the Solution Explorer, yet partial classes don't get nested as advertised (for example: Class.One.cs and Class.Two.cs don't get nested under Class.cs)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022 and https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/6579 (it's no longer a preview feature by the way) **EDIT** I did not understand that it's **disabled by default** and that one has to manually choose "Web" for it to work

Answer (score 1):

> Same answer as @Matthew Watson, except without the "Add the ItemGroup
> entry to the .csproj file" paragraph, because it's a standard feature
> in VS2022 (17.5.x or higher)

**The nesting of .cs files is disabled by default** (some Microsoft tracker says it's because of performance issues).

**Enable it by choosing "Web" yourself (even in a non-Web project -- that's the point)**, by clicking on the nesting button above the files tree in the Solution Explorer:

[image]